# How to get the position of a field using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I got stuck in one area. I need to identify the positions of the `PDAcroForm` fields in one pdf. I need to do some processing with the x and y value of the fields.

Any idea how to do this? Is the information present in the COS object?

Comment: We can get the text position . But i dont know how to get the form field position. Refer this link and try it. http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html

Comment: @SAN3: Yeah i have got the position of the text. But i want to get the position of the field. My requirement is that i need to convert the complete PDF to html. But in my pdf there will be some form elements too. I don't think PDF box has the capability to convert the formelements. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem today. The following code works in my case:

```
private PDRectangle getFieldArea(PDField field) {
  COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getDictionary();
  COSArray fieldAreaArray = (COSArray) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.RECT);

  float left = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(0)).doubleValue();
  float bottom = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(1)).doubleValue();
  float right = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(2)).doubleValue();
  float top = (float) ((COSFloat) fieldAreaArray.get(3)).doubleValue();

  return new PDRectangle(new BoundingBox(left, bottom, right, top));
}
```

Edit: karthicks code is shorter. So I use this code now:

```
private PDRectangle getFieldArea(PDField field) {
  COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getDictionary();
  COSArray fieldAreaArray = (COSArray) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.RECT);
  PDRectangle result = new PDRectangle(fieldAreaArray);
  return result;
}
```

And you can use this code if you want to test that the returned rectangle is correct:

```
private void printRect(final PDPageContentStream contentStream, final PDRectangle rect) throws IOException {
  contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.YELLOW);
  contentStream.drawLine(rect.getLowerLeftX(), rect.getLowerLeftY(), rect.getLowerLeftX(), rect.getUpperRightY()); // left
  contentStream.drawLine(rect.getLowerLeftX(), rect.getUpperRightY(), rect.getUpperRightX(), rect.getUpperRightY()); // top
  contentStream.drawLine(rect.getUpperRightX(), rect.getLowerLeftY(), rect.getUpperRightX(), rect.getUpperRightY()); // right
  contentStream.drawLine(rect.getLowerLeftX(), rect.getLowerLeftY(), rect.getUpperRightX(), rect.getLowerLeftY()); // bottom
  contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: I did something simillar to this.I am typing that as an answer so that people can refer both the codes.

Comment: @karthick: Is this answer correct? Than please mark it as answered. If it is not correct: What are you missing?

Comment: I'm trying to use printRect, but don't see anything in the output. Could you put up an entire working example please?

Comment: @MarkWaschkowski: Sorry, but I don´t have this example anymore. I sometimes forgot to close the contentStream. You also saved the pdf again?!

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer does not work anymore. I have tried the approach and received `NullPointerException` for some elements. In PDFBOX 2.x, you can obtain the rectangle without querying the COS object tree directly.

The information about the field position is stored in `PDAnnotationWidget`. There can be more widgets associated with the field. To obtain the first one (without checking whether these is one).

```
PDRectangle rectangle = field.getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
```

To obtain all rectangles (in cases there can be more):

```
List<PDRectangle> rectangles = field.getWidgets().stream().map(PDAnnotation::getRectangle).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *"The accepted answer does not work anymore"* - more to the point: it never worked for your PDF. It only works for form fields with only a single widget merged into the form field. This often is the case but not always.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get the details like this

```
   COSDictionary trailer = document.getDocument().getTrailer();
   COSDictionary root = (COSDictionary) trailer.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ROOT);
   COSDictionary acroForm = (COSDictionary) root.getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("AcroForm"));
   if (null != acroForm) {
    COSArray fields1 = (COSArray) acroForm.getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("Fields"));
    for (int l = 0; l < fields1.size(); l++) {
     COSDictionary field = (COSDictionary) fields1.getObject(l);
     COSArray rectArray= (COSArray)field.getDictionaryObject("Rect");
     PDRectangle mediaBox = new PDRectangle( rectArray ); 
System.out.println("mediaBox: " + mediaBox.getLowerLeftX()  +"||" +mediaBox.getLowerLeftY());
System.out.println("mediaBox: " + mediaBox.getUpperRightX()  +"||" + mediaBox.getUpperRightY());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for the latest PdfBox dependency releases

```
private PDRectangle getFieldArea(PDField field) {
    COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getCOSObject();
    COSArray fieldAreaArray = (COSArray) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.RECT);
    PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle(fieldAreaArray);
    System.out.println(rectangle);
    return rectangle;
}
```